# Weird behavior in ListView GetView() method position

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I've a custom adapter for my ListView  where I send to it a List, and if the position is in the list then the imageview (that is in the custom row) change its src to another.. Here is the GetView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.start_row, null); // line
                                                                    // 47
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tv_SuraName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Start_Name);

        holder.tv_SuraName.setTypeface(Font);
        holder.tv_PageNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Start_Numbering);
        holder.im_Audio = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Start_ImageView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv_SuraName.setText(SuraList_SuraNamesCode[position]);
    holder.tv_PageNumber.setText(Integer.toString(PageNumber[position]));
    holder.im_Audio.setOnClickListener(new imageViewClickListener(position));
    if (TilawaAvailable.contains(position))
        holder.im_Audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.quran_list_audioavailable);
    return convertView;
}
```

I send a List with 1 position.If I scroll the ListView slowly, this works good and only 1 imageview gets changed as it should be. But if I scroll fast, other imagesviews that are close to the correct position also gets changed!
Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't ever set the imageResource to something else if position isn't contained in your list. When the view with the custom image leaves the screen it is probably getting placed at a lower position in the list and getting reused.

Try changing this:

```
if (TilawaAvailable.contains(position))
        holder.im_Audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.quran_list_audioavailable);
```

To this:

```
if (TilawaAvailable.contains(position))
        holder.im_Audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.quran_list_audioavailable);
else
        holder.im_audio.setImageResource(r.drawable.SOME_THING_ELSE);
```

Comment: Thanks, putting else did the trick. But the default src image in the custom_row.xml is set to the one I want if the List<Integer> doesnt contain its position, so why does it get changed?

Comment: I believe this is due to the fact that the Views get reused and if that view contained the image rather than the default resource, it could potentially show.

Comment: @Omar hooked82 is correct. If a view that contained the custom image gets re-used the elsewhere in the list it will still contain the custom image. The rule is when you get a view to convert you should make sure that everything you need customized gets customized.